# Alternative to GTK WIn7

Tags: gtk

I have begun to use GTK(2), and I find that the workings of the library to be very good, but the documentation sucks.

I want to upgrade to GTK3, but it seems I need to install something called packman. That is a difficult philosophical step for me. Why can't I simply download a zip file(s) somewhere?

The documentation uses a lot of words without saying much, and the downloads want you to download stuff OTHER then gtk in order to get gtk. Why don't they simply have a GTK package and let me decide if I need all the other stuff.

Also, I have been reading on forums, even if I do the packman stuff, it still isn't enough for C::B.

Anyway, that is mostly a rant, what I'd really like is a suggestion to an alternative to GTK+.

Here are some of my requirements...

#1, It must NOT be an interpreter. Using Code::Blocks and C, I get an exe file and I'd like to continue that way.

#2 It must be programmable using C. I'd really like to stick wiith C::B, but I guess in a pinch I can use Eclipse (although that is another nightmare I won't get into here.)

#3 GTK requires a bunch of DLL's to be shipped along with the exe file. It would be ideal if the entire target could be included in the single exe without having to rely on external dll's or .net framework or other external stuff.

Any suggestions woule be apreaciated.

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 1):

You best bet is to give a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#High-level_widget_toolkits

If you wan to stick to C and not C++, then Qt is out.
The other that stands out is [EFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlightenment_Foundation_Libraries). I've never used it myself, but it has good reputation and probably your best bet if you want to quit GTK+ and stick to C. However I don't know how easy it is to use it on Windows.

---

Now about GTK+:

> Also, I have been reading on forums, even if I do the packman stuff, it still isn't enough for C::B.

There are people here that use GTK+ with Code::Blocks, so I don't get what kind of problem you're referring to.

Then your other problems:

> The documentation uses a lot of words without saying much

Examples?

> the downloads want you to download stuff OTHER then gtk in order to get gtk

What you don't get is that GTK+ is more that just the libgtk library. It has dependencies on a lot of other libraries, like glib, cairo, pango, etc. In the past there used to be a bundle or installer to have that installed on Windows, but people would mess up on setting the environment up based on their needs and give up. As the GTK+ manpower for the Windows platform is limited, the GTK+ team delegated the distribution of the GTK+ binaries to the MSYS2 project.

MSYS2 is a popular project that provides a lot of open source software already built for Windows, and solves the problem of building and installing dependencies by hand for the user. This step is made to make installation simpler, not harder. In a handful of commands you have GTK+ and all its dependencies installed for your platform, and can start coding your app. Another command and you have python and the python GTK+ bindings installed and can get started. Want to depend on another popular library? Chances are MSYS already provides it.

Windows has been known for decades to be bad on dependency management. If package management wasn't a a pain point on Windows, then stuff like [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) or [conan](https://conan.io/) wouldn't exist.

Your philosophical reluctance is merely that: philosophical. Sure GTK+ on Windows isn't perfect. With MSYS2 you will get packages built with gcc so the debug symbols are not compatible with the Visual Studio debugger and you will need to use gdb instead. But on your other question you say you use gcc and loathe Visual Studio, so this should not be a blocker to you.

> GTK requires a bunch of DLL's to be shipped along with the exe file. It would be ideal if the entire target could be included in the single exe without having to rely on external dll's or .net framework or other external stuff.

This is not possible for the moment as static compilation of GTK+ isn't supported. The redistribution of an app, however, isn't as easy as I'd like it to be. The best way on Windows to redistribute your app while using MSYS2 is to create a pacman package for your app, listing its dependencies, then call pacman to install your app on an empty directory and tell it to install all your dependencies there too. The result will be a directory that you can redistribute, with a self-contained installation of your app and all its dependencies, GTK+ included.

Comment: Thank you @liberforce I really appreciate it when someone takes the time to expound so much information. I will look into EFL. I have created a virtual machine for testing stuff and I may just have to alter my snobbish attitude about MSYS2. But that, and the other packages you mention, is just another learning curve on top of GTK. I really like doing all the programming myself. I understand the need for higher level languages like Python and Java, they do make it easier for cross platform compatibility, but I learned assembly on the MOT 6800 and really like the total flexibility of using C.